# Print chapter on right side

Tags: books

I want to have a twoside document, left pages should be aligned more to the left and right pages more to the right. Also, when I begin a chapter this should always begin on the right side. All the pages before introduction should have roman numbering, and the pages after the contents should have arabic numbering.

Thus, Chapter one should start at page number 1, at the right hand side of the document, with an increased left margin. I figured the latex book style should cope with this quite easily, below is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twopage]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\frontmatter
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \blindtext
\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
    \blindtext
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{abstract}
\blindtext[6]

\mainmatter

\chapter{introduction}
\blindtext[6]

\end{document}
```

[image: minimal example]

The problems are:

- The titlepage is the first page, and should start with an increased left margin, however, it starts with an increased right margin.
- The abstract is the first chapter, and thus it should start on the right side, with an increased left margin, this is also not true. Same goes for the introduction.

I tried the options openright, openleft, and openany, all three have no effect.

How to solve?

edit: Added the frontmatter and mainmatter. Still no effect.

Comment: Have you tried to put `\frontmatter` just before `\begin{document}` and  `\mainmatter` just before the first chapter ?

Comment: Yes, this solves the page numbering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jérôme Dequeker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/85803/j%c3%a9r%c3%b4me-dequeker) suggests in the comments, try `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` for the page numbering. For the margins, use e.g. the [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package. You can easily set the inner and outer page margins. When you are satisfied with the page setup, you can drop the `showframe` option. I have also changed the `openright` `\documentclass` option to `twopage`. See the code below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twopage]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[showframe, inner=4cm, outer=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

    \begin{titlepage}
        \blindtext
    \end{titlepage}

    \begin{titlepage}
        \blindtext
    \end{titlepage}

    \chapter*{abstract}
    \blindtext[6]

\mainmatter

    \chapter{introduction}
    \blindtext[6]

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

The book class in default adds a so-called "margin note" box to the **outer edge** (you can type into the margin note box e.g. by the standard `\marginpar` command). That is, in fact, what you see when not using the geometry package (which I assume sets it to zero). The `twopage` option sets the outer and inner margins as you would expect. See the example below. Here, I have used the showframe package to show the margins without resetting them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twopage]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage[showframe, inner=4cm, outer=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}

    \begin{document}

        \frontmatter

        \begin{titlepage}
            \blindtext
        \end{titlepage}

        \begin{titlepage}
            \blindtext
        \end{titlepage}

        \chapter*{abstract}
        \blindtext[6]

        \mainmatter

        \chapter{introduction}
        \blindtext[1]
        \marginpar{\textbf{This is a margin note:} \blindtext[1]}

        \blindtext[2]

        \blindtext[3]
    \end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This makes the chapters start at the right side, however, the margins are not the same as without the geometry package. Basically the geometry package forces the margins in the right way, but they dont have the same distance as before. Still not what I am looking for

Comment: I have added some explanation of the phenomena you are seeing. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ah yes. I figured the margins are there for binding purposes. So a wider margin corresponds to the side closest to the bind.