# How to print title chapters on the right side and odd pages on right side in the book class

Tags: page-breaking, chapters, texstudio, books

I am writing my thesis in book class but I figured out that my title chapters are appearing on the left side of the pdf instead of right. I see some discussions that chapter title page must be appear on the right side and also odd pages should be on the right side. I have tried several but not working. Is it because of some package error ?

I have tried this [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295694/print-chapter-on-right-side) but not working. my compiler is XeLaTeX. My MWE is,

[image: this is the output]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}

\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage{newunicodechar} % It is used to remove the error due to the previous document class

\usepackage{booktabs}           %for table lines

\usepackage{textgreek,stackengine}          %for a dot over the greek letters

\newunicodechar{ﬁ}{fi} 

\newunicodechar{ﬀ}{ff}

\UseRawInputEncoding

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref} 

\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
filecolor=magenta,      
urlcolor=cyan,
}

\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{natbib} 

\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{glos} 

\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage{setspace}

 \usepackage{fancyhdr}  

 \pagestyle{fancy}

 \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\thepage}

 \fancyhead[LO]{\small \emph{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}

 \fancyhead[RE]{\small \emph{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}

 \fancyfoot[L,R,C]{}

 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}


  \newcommand{\chapabstract}[1]{
   \begin{quote}\singlespacing\small  \rule{11.5cm}{1pt}\\#1\vskip-4mm\rule{11.5cm}{1pt}\end{quote}
   }
 \newcommand{\publn}{
  \begin{quote}
    \singlespacing\small
   \end{quote}
   }

   \begin{document}

   \frontmatter

   \pagenumbering{roman}

   \include{firstpage}

   \include{frontmatter}

   \tableofcontents

   \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

   \listoftables

   \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

    \mainmatter

    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \input{intro}       %%Chapter 1%%

    \input{Materialia}  %%Chapter 2%%

    \cleardoublepage

     \singlespacing

     \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

     \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

      \bibliography{RSC}

       \end{document}
```

Comment: forgive me for the extended MWE.

Comment: The default arrangement for the `book` class is for odd-numbered pages to be on the right.  That this is actually what is happening is confirmed by the location of the even page number, which would be the *outside* edge when printed and bound.  Some pdf-readers try to "save space" on a screen by starting on the left, but *they're wrong*!  One thing that should be fixed in your file is the location where `hyperref` is loaded; it should be near the end of the preamble; packages that should be loaded later are named in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to use `xelatex` it comes back with `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` so I used `lualatex` instead on your MWE, which I edited slightly to comment out the files you did not provide, replacing them with a simple version of what I assume their contents are.

```
% chapterprob.tex SE 555584

\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{book}    
\usepackage{newunicodechar} % It is used to remove the error due to the previous document class    
\usepackage{booktabs}           %for table lines
\usepackage{textgreek,stackengine}          %for a dot over the greek letters
\newunicodechar{ﬁ}{fi}     
\newunicodechar{ﬀ}{ff}    
\UseRawInputEncoding    
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}    
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
filecolor=magenta,      
urlcolor=cyan,
}    
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{textcomp}    
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphics}    
\usepackage{natbib}     
\usepackage[symbols,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,acronym]{glossaries-extra}    
\makeglossaries    
\loadglsentries{glos}    
\usepackage{threeparttable}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{setspace}    
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}    
 \pagestyle{fancy}    
 \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\thepage}    
 \fancyhead[LO]{\small \emph{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}    
 \fancyhead[RE]{\small \emph{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}    
 \fancyfoot[L,R,C]{}    
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}    
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}    
  \newcommand{\chapabstract}[1]{
   \begin{quote}\singlespacing\small  \rule{11.5cm}{1pt}\\#1\vskip-4mm\rule{11.5cm}{1pt}\end{quote}
   }
 \newcommand{\publn}{
  \begin{quote}
    \singlespacing\small
   \end{quote}
   }

   \begin{document}

   \frontmatter

   \pagenumbering{roman}

   \include{firstpage}

   \include{frontmatter}

   \tableofcontents

   \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

   \listoftables

   \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}

    \mainmatter

%    \setcounter{page}{1} % \mainmatter sets this

%    \pagenumbering{arabic} % \mainmatter sets this

%    \input{intro}       %%Chapter 1%%
\chapter{Introduction}
Some text.

%    \input{Materialia}  %%Chapter 2%%
\chapter{Materiala}
More text.

    \cleardoublepage

     \singlespacing

     \renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

     \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

      \bibliography{RSC}

       \end{document}
```

The above MWE starts each chapter on the right hand (recto, odd) page.

Your problem may be with `xelatex` but probably not. More likely is what you have in your `intro.tex` and `Materiala.tex` files which you haven't given us an inkling of.

Comment: Hi Wilson, Thanks for your answer. I have tried this, but my Texstudio is printing on the left side only. I also downloaded Texmaker and run my code. Same, I cannot find the  the error. In my code, I tried by deactivating rest of the chapter and also deactivated the user package one by one. But still the effect remain same.